# How to update existing MySQL table when one of the HTML form field is submitted blank where default value for all asked columns is NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

After login user needs to fill another form. There is a single table for this website called `users` with columns named as-

```
Ten_School_name, Ten_Board, Ten_Percentage, Twl_School_Name, Twl_Board, Twl_Percentage
```

`Ten_School_name`, `Twl_School_Name` is set to `VARCHAR(70)` and default value as `NULL`
`Ten_Board`, `Twl_Board` is set to `VARCHAR(10)` and default value as `NULL`
`Ten_Percentage`, `Twl_Percentage` is set to `int(3)` and default value as `NULL`

The `Username`, `Email` and `Password` are three other columns, these get occupied when the user registers on the website and rest are set to NULL as the default value. When I am submitting the form by filling all the six fields then the form is submitted successfully but if any field is left blank it gives the error from processing script `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Twl_Percentage' at row 2`

*I have already wasted lot of time looking for the solution. I hope someone here will solve my problem.*

**Here is my form-**

```
 <form id="msform" action="includes/cand-reg-dbs.php" method="POST">
    <!--10th Class Details-->
    <label>10th School Name</label><input type="text" name="tenth-school"><br />

    <label>10th Board</label>
    <select name="tenth-board">
        <option name="tenth-board1" value="icse">ICSE</option>
        <option name="tenth-board2" value="cbse">CBSE</option>
        <option name="tenth-board3" value="up-board">UP Board</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>10th Percentage</label>
    <input type="number" name="tenth-percent">
    <br />


    <!--12th Class Details-->
    <label>12th School Name</label><input type="text" name="twl-school"><br />

    <label>12th Board</label>
    <select name="twl-board">
        <option name="twl-board1" value="icse">ISE</option>
        <option name="twl-board2" value="cbse">CBSE</option>
        <option name="twl-board3" value="up-board">UP Board</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>12th Percentage</label>
    <input type="number" name="twl-percent">

    <input type="submit" name="submita" id="" class="" value="Save" /></form>
```

**Here is my php script to process the data-**

```
if (isset($_POST['submita'])) {

    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "jobin";

    $con = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

 if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        echo $user;
        $eml = $_SESSION['cand_email'];
        echo $eml;
    }



$tenthSchool = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tenth-school']);
$tenthBoard = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tenth-board']);
$tenthPercent = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tenth-percent']);
$twlSchool = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['twl-school']);
$twlBoard = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['twl-board']);
$twlPercent = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['twl-percent']);

$sqlsd = "UPDATE users 
SET 
Ten_School_Name = '$tenthSchool',
Ten_Board = '$tenthBoard',
Ten_Percentage = '$tenthPercent',
Twl_School_Name = '$twlSchool',
Twl_Board = '$twlBoard',
Twl_Percentage = '$twlPercent'
WHERE
Email = '$eml';";



if(!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$resultsd = mysqli_query($con, $sqlsd);

if(!$resultsd)
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if ($resultsd) {
    header("Location: ../candidate-registration.php?sd=success");
}   

} else {
echo "nothing";
}
```

Comment: *"it gives the error from processing script Could not update data:"* - Ok.. .and what's the rest of the error? You are using `mysqli_connect_error()` after all. However, that is the wrong function, you need to use `mysqli_error($con)`. here.

Comment: ok I have changed the function as you told. Here is the error message-`Incorrect integer value: 'CMS School' for column 'Ten_School_Name' at row 2`

Comment: change the column type to varchar and set the length for it

Comment: It is already set to `VARCHAR(70)` and default value as NULL

Comment: well then, you probably have an `id` column of sorts and isn't an AI, hard to say without seeing the schema for it.

Comment: `id` column is set to `int(11)` and is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` with default value as `none`

Comment: well... I don't see an `Email` column in what you stated as being columns above. Sorry, but the question is getting too unclear for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the columns from NULL to NOT NULL and set the default as an empty string '' on your table. This way you can use a more secure prepared statement like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET Ten_School_Name = ?, Ten_Board = ?, Ten_Percentage = ?, Twl_School_Name = ?, Twl_Board = ?, Twl_Percentage = ? WHERE Email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssissis", $tenthSchool, $tenthBoard, $tenthPercent, 
$twlSchool, $twlBoard, $twlPercent, $eml);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

If you can't change your columns, you have to write your query using only the fields that are not empty. Like this:

```
$sqlsd2 = "";
if ($tenthSchool != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Ten_School_Name = '$tenthSchool', ";
if ($tenthBoard != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Ten_Board = '$tenthBoard', ";
if ($tenthPercent != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Ten_Percentage = $Ten_Percentage, ";
if ($twlSchool != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Twl_School_Name = '$twlSchool', "
if ($twlBoard != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Twl_Board = '$twlBoard', "
if ($twlPercent != "") { $sqlsd2 .= "Twl_Percentage = $twlPercent ";

if($sqlsd2 !="")
{ //update)
 $sqlsd = "UPDATE users SET " . $sqlsd2 . "WHERE Email = '$eml'";
}
else
{
//nothing to update
}
```

Notice this second approach is not as secure as the first one, as mysqli_real_escape_string does not completely avoid mysql injection. You must use a prepared statement.

There is a way of making a dynamic prepared statement using call_user_func_array(), sometimes I could not escape doing this, but it is more complex. I suggest simply changing your columns and doing the prepared statement.